# Let users know that card is not final draft?

Tags: usability-testing

In a card game I've developed I want to add something that makes it clear that the cards are not a final revision, and that it may change?

I was thinking about water marking the entire card with 'draft', but it doesn't look fantastic.

Here is a quick example i've knocked up just to play-test the game.
[image: Place holder card]

Please note that the image does not belong to me, and the text is just a 'fun' placeholder.

Comment: To help us understand the context of your app/game you need to help us with some prototypes. Or existing mockups. We need to get the feel of the existing developed content to suggest something which goes with it

Comment: I'll get an example when I'm home later.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better for us to see, what the cards will look like. The watermark might be not visible if the graphics are very complex. Just like @setht said - the colored borders might be a good idea, but I would add some "ribbons" that overlap the card, but at the same time stand out of it and are clearly visible. Combining colors and labels should give a clear information about the card status.

For example, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I've added a rough draft with placeholders etc..

Answer (score 1):

You did not give us a lot of background information but have you tried adding a simple icon/flag containing a text 'draft' or 'wip'?

[image: example image]

It doesn't have to be very invasive. Just enough to draw attention, not so much it distracts from the artwork. Make sure that whoever pays for the game or cards, knows there are unfinished products in the stack. If people know it's still a work in progress, they will understand the icon.

Comment: I've added a rough draft with placeholders etc..

Answer (score 0):

A colored border could convey this meaning without obscuring the card whatsoever, but be careful with the color and thickness so it's not too distracting.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use only color to convey info, since some of your users are likely to be colorblind or otherwise visually impaired. Color plus another indicator (for example, an icon or tag) would be better.

Comment: @KenMohnkern Very true! Thank you for bringing up this point.

Comment: I've added a rough draft with placeholders etc..